# Angular2/Rxjs nested maps with conditions in guard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd stuck with Rxjs operators.

This is a part of Angular's guard `canActivate`

```
const ifNoPatientCondition$ = this.dataService.getList().map(pl => {
  console.log('im here'); // <<< this message not showing
  const found = findOnlyAvailablePatients(pl);
  if (found[0] === 1) {
    this.stateService.patient.setCurrent(found[1]);
    this.dataService.getPatientData(pid);
    // return Observable.of(true);
    return true;
  } else {
    if (found[0] === 0) {
      this.stateService.app.message.send('Wrong patient status');
    } else if (found[0] === -1) {
      this.stateService.app.message.send('Wrong patient ID');
    }
    this.subscribes.forEach(subscribe => subscribe.unsubscribe());
    this.stateService.navigate('/patients');
    // return Observable.of(false);
    // return false;
  }
});

const warnOkCondition$ = this.stateService.patient.getCurrent().pipe(mergeMap(pat => {
  if (!pat || pat.patient_id !== pid) { // <<< i'm interested with this condition
    console.log('there is no patient!', pat); // <<< i see this message
    return ifNoPatientCondition$; // <<< but cannot reach this line
  } else {
    if (pat.status === 'TREATMENT_COMPLETE') {
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
    return Observable.of(true);
  }
}));

return warningDialog().pipe(concatMap(warningResult => {
  if (!warningResult) { // <<< if clicked No
    this.stateService.navigate('/patients');
    return Observable.of(false);
  } else { // <<< 'Yes'
    console.log('you are the best');
    return warnOkCondition$;
  }
}));
```

`warningDialog()` shows a dialog and returns observable of result.
If i clicked **No**, code works right: guard returns false and router navigate to `/patients`.

else if i clicked **Yes**, `warnOkCondition$` works partially right (i'm interesting with first condition (with `console.log`)): i see message in console, but cannot reach next line - `ifNoPatientCondition$` code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Types if you are working with Typescript. It is not clear what is an array and what is an Observable. Since `warnOkCondition$` returns `Observable.of(true/false)` on some conditions, I assume `this.dataService.getList()` returns an Observable as well, and not a list, even though `pl` has no `$`-suffix at the end. In this case you need to subscribe to `ifNoPatientCondition$` if you want it to be executed.

You might want to use `switchMap` or `mergeMap` here. https://netbasal.com/understanding-mergemap-and-switchmap-in-rxjs-13cf9c57c885

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes, `getList()` returns a Subject asObservable, same as `getCurrent()`. I cannot subscribe because Angular's `canActivate` should return either boolean, Observable<boolean> or Promise<boolean>. Once i have no boolean, i thought i should map boolean from other observables depending on their values. Already tried to use `switchMap` and `mergeMap`. Also tried to subscribe to `ifNoPatientCondition$` before returning. Same result :(

Comment: What is the implementation of `this.dataService.getList()`? Put a `console.log()` in `getList` and check if it gets called. My suspicion is that it is not. I see two solutions: make `getList` return a list and not an observable of a list or put mergeMap in the right place. I recommend the first one. You want to perform a synchronous operation and always need to wait for the List to be returned, so there is no need to get an Observable.

Comment: Added log to `getList()`:

`getList() called! `... `gotpatient.guard.ts:124 you are the best` ... 
`gotpatient.guard.ts:108 there is no patient!`

I'll try to switch from asynchronous List to List (or event to BehaviorSubject) tomorrow and report about result. Thanks!

Comment: Solved this problem in more elegant (in context of using Angular) way: created a separate guard :)